# Stream video frames from a Pi in real time

Tags: python, rest, web, tcp, raspberry-pi2

I am currently dealing with a Pi camera on a Raspberry Pi 2B. I would like to stream input images (which I am continuously collecting when turned on) in real-time to a server that runs computer vision software. The processing on my server then returns data based on the image recognition that has to be sent back to the Raspberry Pi.

Since the Raspberry Pi's video capturing and WiFi capabilities might not be too overwhelming, I think about the best way to stream such data, both images/video frames from the Pi and (maybe) JSON-formatted table-like generated data in the opposite direction.

I thought about the following possibilities which I want to implement in Python (easier) or C++ (faster if necessary):

Frames

- entire frame in REST API, accessible through GET
- streaming via TCP
- pushing and pulling from a SQL database on the server

Generated data

- pushing and pulling from a SQL database on the server
- pushing and pulling from a Redis database on the server
- REST API on server, collecting via GET on the Pi

There are definitely other possibilities which I might not know yet. So you're welcome to recommend your favourite solution. I am really looking forward to hear about the pros and cons of each technology.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same questions about frames streaming. Did you conclude?

Comment: Not yet, sorry.